# Interface parameters or what does it ask for?

Tags: java

I'm learning Java. And I came across a code that I can't understand. The constructor of the class requires to pass to it an interface in the parameters, which implements this class? Or what does he want? Help please. Here's the code.

> ```java
> public interface ProgressListener {
>     void updateProgress(long loaded, long total);
>
>     boolean hasCancelled(); }
>
> public abstract class DownloadListener implements ProgressListener {
>
>     /**
>      * Local file length for resuming download. 0 if local file not exist
>      */
>     public long getLocalLength() {
>         return 0;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Used for <tt>If-None-Match</tt> or <tt>If-Range</tt>. MD5 or <tt>null</tt> if not applicable or not known
>      * @see <a href="http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-132">rfc 2616</a>
>      */
>     public String getETag() {
>         return null;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Start position after server response
>      */
>     public void setStartPosition(long position) {
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Content length after server response. 0 if not known
>      * @throws DownloadNoSpaceAvailableException if no local space for content
>      */
>     public void setContentLength(long length)
>         throws DownloadNoSpaceAvailableException {
>     }
>
>     public abstract OutputStream getOutputStream(boolean append)
>             throws IOException;
>
>     @Override
>     public void updateProgress(long loaded, long total) {
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean hasCancelled() {
>         return false;
>     }
>
>     public void setETag(String etag) {
>     }
>
>     public void setContentType(String contentType) {
>     } }
>
> public class FileDownloadListener extends DownloadListener {
>
>     private final File saveTo;
>     private final ProgressListener progressListener;
>
>     public FileDownloadListener(File saveTo, ProgressListener progressListener) {
>         this.saveTo = saveTo;
>         this.progressListener = progressListener;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public OutputStream getOutputStream(boolean append)
>             throws FileNotFoundException {
>         return new FileOutputStream(saveTo, append);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public long getLocalLength() {
>         return saveTo.length();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void updateProgress(long loaded, long total) {
>         if (progressListener != null) {
>             progressListener.updateProgress(loaded, total);
>         }
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean hasCancelled() {
>         return progressListener != null && progressListener.hasCancelled();
>     } 
> }
> ```

When creating an instance of FileDownloadListener, the second parameter it asks to pass ProgressListener. What to do?

Comment: You cannot pass interface. But you can pass **instance** of **class** that **implements** that interface.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski:  [Liskov substitution](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual_articles/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design#liskov-substitution-principle) means that this constructor takes *any* class that implements the interface, so...yeah you can pass that in.

Comment: That's where I have a problem. This interface implements the class that I cannot create an instance of. Because he asks for an instance there that implements this interface. What to do in this situation?

Comment: Interface cannot implement a class. It is other way around. Interface (I think this name is very unfortunate) is a contract (which ia far better name for what it is for) that guarantees that **any** class that claims to implement it, in fact did that. Class can have more methods than interface lists but that's fine as it **cannot** have less. All contract methods **must** be implemented. Period. So type hinting by interface and not concrete implementation is more flexible and lets you i. e. easily swap implementations for tests etc. There's more of course but I hit the comment length limit ;)

Comment: Hello. I want to say thank you. Your advice helped me. I implemented the interface and passed it to the constructor! Everything works!!!